# Insights post_impressions return empty

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-fql

The following FQL always returns empty JSON response. I have all the necessary permissions set up and I tried all the other suggestions mentioned here.

What else can I try?

SELECT metric, value FROM insights WHERE object_id= '100002643961484_444481312316664'  AND metric='post_impressions' AND period = 0

Also

SELECT post_id, impressions FROM stream WHERE source_id = me()

returns null for all the posts. Are there any other restrictions except permissions that make requests return null and empty values?

```
{
  "post_id": "100002643961484_444585178972944", 
  "impressions": null
}, 
{
  "post_id": "100002643961484_444481312316664", 
  "impressions": null
}, 
{
  "post_id": "100002643961484_444481068983355", 
  "impressions": null
},
```